# Android back key/button, how to use perfectly?

Tags: android

I'm developing an app which downloads stuff from the internet and displays, more like web browser. The more deep you go in, the back key stack fills up. So now when you press back key, it loads last URL from the list and then keep goes till the first visited URL and on the last time, back key is pressed, the app closes.

But there is a problem, assume you are browsing for a long time with so many URLs in back-key list. Now you want to close the app but you will have to keep press back key till the last URL and then it will get close. It's not a good idea, I mean its very annoying. If I want to close the app it must be done in a single tap. So I came up with an idea to put an exit button but it still a bad design for android.

I'm wondering if there is any better way you guys can suggest, that would be very nice.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home

Comment: yes that's same as exit button

Comment: give a exit button in the menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One suggestion: You can create a onLongPress event on your back button. This is usualy done in a lot of hardware/software applications, so a lot of people should try that by intuition. If the user press once the back button, this will go back, if he stays longer on the back button, this will close the app, or ask him to confirm the app close in confirmation dialog.

So, in your case, you will have:

```
@override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
    {
        // close the app
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

Even better, you can implement this, and add a menu, when the user clicks the menu button, he will see the exit icon, and exit like that.

Answer (score 1):

I think exit `Button` is not always a bad option, specially when you have to need some thing like this. But you can think about another solution-

`onbackpress` normally exit the `webview` and add a `backbutton` like `webbrowsers`.

Comment: I always preferred long back-key press to close the app. But there is no way to know it.

Comment: and you can handle long key press too .. public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO any work around to close the app are bad ideas and bad design practices for Android. If the user wants to immediately exit the app he'll use the Home button, not the back button, that's what the home button is for, that's why it's there.

again it's my opinion, but I believe that a good design in this type of application (you mentioned a web browser, type of thing) is that for example the user wants to start the browser from the beginning of the navigation tree, you use the Up button (as suggested on one of the comments http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home) to bring your app to the initial state. You can use a intent with a CLEAR_TOP flag to remove any existing Backstack.

Comment: But not every user know how to use android home button. And then comes negative ratings.

Comment: I've noticed you marked the answer with the BackLongPress as the accepted answer. Do you think a user that does not know about the home button (the most central button on the whole system) will understand a long press?

Comment: Some users don't want to minimize the app(home button), they want to close it completely. Yes they wont be aware of long press but back key is only one who suppose to do that. I'm thinking of rapid back key press as an option too. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the Milos' answer is the best way to do it... Too you can add the 'Exit' option as an item on the menu, check this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_option_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.exit:
        // CLose your app
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And this is the layout for the menu: your_option_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/exit"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_exit"
          android:title="@string/Exit" />
</menu>
```